# Removing element from array. Getting null instead of actually removing element/index

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove an element from an array. I am running into an issue where when I run my program and remove a certain index. I get nulls in the place where the element/index should be removed entirely.

My output is when I execute list.display() in the main method is

Tom, Bob, Richard

However after I execute list.remove() and run the program. I get

null, null, Richard.

Any tips?

```
public class MyArrayList implements MyList {

    private Object[] theList;


    public MyArrayList()
    {
        theList = new Object[0];
    }


    public boolean add(Object toAdd){

        if(toAdd != null) {
            Object[] temp = new Object[theList.length + 1];

            for(int i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
                temp[i] = theList[i];
            }
            temp[theList.length] = toAdd;
            theList = temp;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

 public Object remove(int index) {

        if (index >= 0 && index < theList.length) {

            Object[] temp = new Object[theList.length - 1];
            theList[index] = null;

            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
                if (i == index) {
                    continue;
                }
                temp[j++] = theList[i];
                theList = temp;
            }
            return temp;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyArrayList list = new MyArrayList();

        list.add("Tom");
        list.add("Bob");
        list.add("Richard");
        list.display();

        list.remove(0);
        list.remove(1);

        list.display();
        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your code implements MyList which is not available in code, i could not run below sample on your code but you can have below logic in your code. You don't need extra temp array in remove method. Since it an array, you can start traversing array from index which has to be removed and start moving next element by one step before.

```
   public Object remove(int index) {
        if (theList == null || index < 0 || index >= theList.length) { 
        return theList; 
        }
        for (int i = index; i < theList.length; i++) {
            theList[i] = theList[i + 1];
        }
    
    return null;
}
```

You can trim array tail if it has more empty places based on some threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Where you call `list.remove(0)`, you should be assigning the result back to `list` again.  For example:

```
list = list.remove(0);
```

A couple of other things:

1. It's generally a bad idea to change the index variable within a loop.  It's legal, but leads to logic errors that can be difficult to reason about and diagnose.
2. You're getting the `null` in your output because the `remove` method also mutates the `theList` when you execute:

   ```
   theList[index] = null;
   ```

Since you're returning a copy of `theList` you don't need to also set that element of the `theList` array to null.

Answer (score 0):

the code is doing exactly what you asked it to do. Those removed values are null because you have this line

```
theList[index] = null;
```

Also think about what your intentions are.
list.remove(0);  <- this will remove the first element so now list would be Rob, Richard
list.remove(1);  <- this will remove the 2nd element of the modified list (Rob, Richard) so result would be Rob. This is probably not what you want.

instead of this

```
if (i == index) {
      i++; // risk of out of bounds exception
}
```

you probably want this instead

```
if (i == index) {
    continue; 
}
```

Comment: I'm still confused. You're right, I get Bob, null when I run the program.
Where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: list.remove(0) removes the first item in the array.  list.remove(1) removes the 2nd. When  you do remove(0) it modifies the list to then become [Bob, Richard]. Now if you want to remove Bob, you again need to call remove(0).